# How to load html dependencies in node.js azure web app

Tags: html, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

As a disclaimer I'm fairly new to both javascript and Azure. My goal is to build a Tableau web data connector. I have the following scripts.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Facebook Likes</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://connectors.tableau.com/libs/tableauwdc-2.3.latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="FacebookLikes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container container-table">
        <div class="row vertical-center-row">
            <div class="text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <button type = "button" id = "submitButton" class = "btn btn-success" style = "margin: 10px;">Get Facebook Likes!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer((function() {
    // Create the connector object
    var myConnector = tableau.makeConnector();

    // Define the schema
    myConnector.getSchema = function(schemaCallback) {
        var cols = [{
            id: "id",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.int
        }, {
            id: "link",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        }, {
            id: "likes",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.int
        }];

        var tableSchema = {
            id: "Facebook",
            alias: "real-time likes",
            columns: cols
        };

        schemaCallback([tableSchema]);
    };

    // Download the data
    myConnector.getData = function(table, doneCallback) {
        var username = 'xxx'; 
        var password = 'xxx'; 
        var url = 'xxxx';
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open('POST', url, true);

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
            if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)
                tableData = [];

                tableData.push({
                    "id": response.id,
                    "link": response.link,
                    "likes": response.likes,
                    });

                table.appendRows(tableData);
                doneCallback();
                }
            }

        params = username + ';' + password
        xhttp.send(params)
        };

    tableau.registerConnector(myConnector);

    // Create event listeners for when the user submits the form
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submitButton").click(function() {
            tableau.connectionName = "Facebook Likes"; // This will be the data source name in Tableau
            tableau.submit(); // This sends the connector object to Tableau
        });
    });
})).listen(process.env.PORT || 1337);
```

I built and tested the html and javascript locally, and everything works as expected. The only thing that I have added from my dev version is the createServer call. If I do a git push according to Azure documentation the push executes successfully, and I can see the deployment listed in my app under "Deployment Options"; however, when I open the webpage I get the message, "you do not have permission to view this directory or page." My research lead me to include package.json and web.config files as follows.

```
{
  "name": "azure-facebook-likes",
  "author": "Xander",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "application for use with Tableau web data connector to return facebook likes",
  "tags": [
    "facebook",
    "tableau"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node FacebookLikes.js"
  }
}
```

--

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <handlers>
            <!-- indicates that the app.js file is a node.js application to be handled by the iisnode module -->
            <add name="iisnode" path="FacebookLikes.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>

        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <!-- Don't interfere with requests for logs -->
                <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.js\.logs\/\d+\.txt$" />
                </rule>

                <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
                <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">                    
                    <match url="^FacebookLikes.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                </rule>

                <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
                <rule name="StaticContent">
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>

                <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the Node.js application entry point -->
                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="FacebookLikes.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>

    <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true"> 
    </security>

</configuration>
```

With this configuration, when I browse to the web page I get the message, "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." Logging-errors.txt reveals the following, "Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated: ReferenceError: tableau is not defined." The tableau definition comes from the connectors.tableau.com dependency in the html file, but from what I can tell, when I specify

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node FacebookLikes.js"
}
```

in the package.json file the scripts in the html file aren't loading. I have been working on this for a couple days and am bereft of ideas. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get the dependencies to load? Or can someone push me in the right direction as to what I should be looking at? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure has a list of default documents under application settings. I had named my html file FacebookLikes.html, which is (unsurprisingly) not a default document name. I renamed my file index.html, deleted the web.config and package.json files, and removed the create server call from the javascript code (and added a trailing ()), and the web application functions as expected. Conceivably I could add FacebookLikes.html to the default documents, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using should run from the browser rather than from Node.js. You could move the code from `FacebookLikes.js` to the HTML file like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Facebook Likes</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://connectors.tableau.com/libs/tableauwdc-2.3.latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="FacebookLikes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submitButton").click(function() {
                tableau.connectionName = "Facebook Likes"; // This will be the data source name in Tableau
                tableau.submit(); // This sends the connector object to Tableau
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container container-table">
        <div class="row vertical-center-row">
            <div class="text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <button type = "button" id = "submitButton" class = "btn btn-success" style = "margin: 10px;">Get Facebook Likes!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>

    var myConnector = tableau.makeConnector();

    // Define the schema
    myConnector.getSchema = function(schemaCallback) {
        // ...
    };

    // Download the data
    myConnector.getData = function(table, doneCallback) {
        // ...
    };

    tableau.registerConnector(myConnector);

</script>

</html>
```

And then delete `FacebookLikes.js`, `web.config` and `package.json` files as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried it, but I received the "...do not have permission..." message again. The ErrorPage.htm log reveals "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden. The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory. Most likely causes: A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server." I'm not sure how to configure a default document in an Azure environment. This seemed like a great idea that I hadn't thought of. Is there anything else I can try?